# Can you see the stars when it is trickling?

Tags: star, amateur-observing, night-sky

I am writing a book with the following scene in one chapter: It is trickling and my protagonists are outside looking into the night sky, looking to the stars. Reviewing the scene I am wondering: Is this possible? **Can you see the stars when it is trickling, or even when it rains?** Are there images showing this?

Comment: "trickling" is probably the wrong word to use. Do you mean "drizzling" or "showers" or "fog" or what?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes you can. You just need a partly clear sky (to see the stars) and part cloud (to produce the rain).

For an example of suitable conditions, look for pictures of a [moonbow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moonbow).  (I've only seen one once, personally.)

Comment: Wind in the upper atmosphere can help as well - the rain cloud doesn't have to be overhead to get you wet, and the smaller the droplets - the larger a given wind speed will deflect them.

Answer (score 0):

You can simulate this by going outside in clear weather, and spraying water with a hose. It is indeed possible to perceive stars despite precipitation.

However, where there is rain there are often clouds, which would be the bigger problem. But sometimes there is rain with patchy clouds.

Comment: Hi gomennathan - please read existing answers to a post to see if your post will add any value. This is especially the case where there is an accepted answer. I would suggest reading our [about] and [answer] pages for guidance.